# Excel VBA Lock columns containing specific value in a cell

Tags: excel, vba, locking

I have a need to lock all columns containing a specific value in column heading. I've tried the following without success. I realize that I'll have to lock the worksheet after locking the columns. There is something wrong in selecting the column.

I'd appreciate your help.

```
    Sub MultipleFindLike()
  For Each cell In Worksheets("LockTest").Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlToRight))
    If cell Like "COM_*" Then
      Debug.Print "Cell value = " & cell
      Debug.Print "Cell Column = " & cell.Column
      Range(cell, Range(cell).End(xlDown)).Select
    End If
  Next
Worksheets("LockTest").Protect Password:="mypass"
Debug.Print "Done ..."

End Sub
```

Comment: You don't do anything with the selection you make. Also it is not wise to use select. It's better to use the cells explicit adress and use that to lock them. So for example Range("A:A").Locked = true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that the worksheet was already locked and cell-locking statement wouldn't work. Below is what is working. Nevertheless, I welcome more elegant solutions.

```
Sub LockSelectedCells(sheetName As String)
  Dim cell As Range
  Dim sheetProtectPassword As String
  sheetProtectPassword = Range("Reports!sheetProtectPassword")
'  Debug.Print "sheetProtectPassword=" & sheetProtectPassword
  Worksheets(sheetName).Unprotect Password:=sheetProtectPassword
  For Each cell In Worksheets(sheetName).Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlToRight))
    If cell.Value Like "COM_*" Then
'      Debug.Print "Cell value = " & cell
'      Debug.Print "Cell Column = " & cell.Column
'      Debug.Print "A" & cell.Column
      cell.EntireColumn.Locked = False
    End If
  Next
Worksheets(sheetName).Protect Password:=sheetProtectPassword
Debug.Print "Done ..."

End Sub
```